# How to find the root of a function within a range in python

Tags: python, scipy, fsolve

I need to find the `alpha` value in [0,1] of a linear combination `alpha*Id+(1-alpha)*M`, where `Id` is the identity matrix, `M` is a given matrix, such that this linear combination has given mean.

At the moment I am using `scipyt.optimize.fsolve` but it does not admit the range [0,1] as an input. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define `alpha` using a sigmoid function:

```
alpha = 1/(1+exp(-x))
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Based on this definition, alpha will always be in the range `[0, 1]`. Then, you can change the target of the optimization in `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to calibrate the value of `x` instead of `alpha` directly.

The variable `x` is free of constraints, so any optimization method works.

---

PS. This technique is very common in machine learning.

---

PS2. Adding constraints to an optimizer is only important when they are not being fulfilled. So for example, if your `alpha` solution is already in the range `[0,1]`, then you can keep the optimizer as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I have to change also the definition of the function if I change the target ? For example, for a certain matrix, `fsolve` gives 0.28 as root. This is a good value for `alpha` because is in [0,1]. If this value was `x`, then `alpha=1/(1+exp(-0.28)) = 0.57` and the result would be wrong

Comment: Yes, the function has to be changed, such that `x` is the target. But if your system is already working without any constraints (since you get alpha = 0.28), then you can keep everything as it is. Adding constraints is only important, when they are not being respected.

Comment: It is working now with a specific given matrix. In future the input Matrix M can change and the constraints might not be respected.

Comment: Then, try optimizing for `x` :)

Comment: yes, thanks. I guess I also have to change the starting point x0 which is one of the input of fsolve ? When the target is alpha, I set it to 0, if the target is x, what is x0?

Comment: You can give a negative value, like `x0=-4`. This yields `alpha0=0.017986`